# How to stop class variables being overwritten?

Tags: typescript, function, class

I am attempting to make a match 3 game, from a brief I have been given, where the user will always get a match after 4 attempts.
I have a list of 3 objects, each taken from a larger list at random. Each object can draw an image at given coordinates.
A user presses a button, and a random position is given.
one object, taken randomly from the small list, where, depending on what random position was given, it will get it's variables assigned with coordinates for the image specific to that position.
On a 2nd click, another object is taken from the smaller list, it is given another random position, and variables accordingly.
If the two objects are the same, then the player wins. However, the first instance of the object and it's given position variables will have been overwritten when the same object was called again, to make a matching pair. How can I avoid this, or save the first instances variable values?

```
rewardobjects = [
  new rewards(coinImage, 15),
  new rewards(diamondImage, 16),
  new rewards(goldImage, 17),
  new rewards(notesImage, 18),
  new rewards(ringImage, 19),
]; //full list of objects

if (clickCounter < 2) {
  let randomRewards = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < chosenRewards.length; i++) {
      while (rewardobjects[randomRewards] == chosenRewards[i]) {
        randomRewards = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
      }
    }

    chosenRewards.push(rewardobjects[randomRewards]); //on first loop through, take 3 different, randomly selected objects from large list, into smaller list
  }
}

let rewardChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); //each loop through (every time the user clicks), take a random object from small list.

if (displayTxt === "1") {
  //assign variables of the object depending on which position they end up.

  chosenRewards[rewardChoice].xIncrementDoor = 15;
  chosenRewards[rewardChoice].yIncrementDoor = 0;
  chosenRewards[rewardChoice].xIncrementReward = 30;
  chosenRewards[rewardChoice].yIncrementReward = 5;
  chosenRewards[rewardChoice].xIncrementTxt = 110;
  chosenRewards[rewardChoice].yIncrementTxt = 100;
  chosenRewards[rewardChoice].draw();
} else if (displayTxt === "2") {
  chosenRewards[rewardChoice].xIncrementDoor = 200;
  chosenRewards[rewardChoice].yIncrementDoor = 0;
  chosenRewards[rewardChoice].xIncrementReward = 210;
  chosenRewards[rewardChoice].yIncrementReward = 5;
  chosenRewards[rewardChoice].xIncrementTxt = 280;
  chosenRewards[rewardChoice].yIncrementTxt = 100;
  chosenRewards[rewardChoice].draw();
} else if (displayTxt == "3") {
  chosenRewards[rewardChoice].xIncrementDoor = 350;
  chosenRewards[rewardChoice].yIncrementDoor = 0;
  chosenRewards[rewardChoice].xIncrementReward = 360;
  chosenRewards[rewardChoice].yIncrementReward = 5;
  chosenRewards[rewardChoice].xIncrementTxt = 430;
  chosenRewards[rewardChoice].yIncrementTxt = 100;
  chosenRewards[rewardChoice].draw();
}

if (clickCounter > 1) {
  //on second loop through, start checking if the objects match with winCheck function.
  winCheck(chosenRewards[rewardChoice]);
  earnedRewards.push(chosenRewards[rewardChoice]); //if true, win check calls win() and ends game, if not, the current random object is added to a list of random objects that have already been used.
} else {
  earnedRewards.push(chosenRewards[rewardChoice]); // on first loop through, add current random object to list of objects that have been used.
}
```

Comment: Have you tried storing the positions into a results array?

Comment: I haven't no, if each object is still being assigned to a position though, then they will still have their values overwritten if called twice, even if the positions are in an array?